# Exploding a Pandas Crosstab Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, pivot-table

I have created a `pandas` `crosstab` table. My data has groupings as shown along the left column, where a particular row can correspond to more than one organization. I would like to 'explode' these out such that values in `[org1, org2]` would be counted in both `org1` and `org2`. Therefore, I am trying to display one row in the `crosstab` table for each organization (i.e., one row for each `org1`, `org2`, `org3`, and `org4`).

[image]

Is there a good function or series of functions I can call to accomplish this explosion/semi-level of detail calculation? I have not been successful.

Here is some sample data:

[image]

Here is some expected output... assuming I did my mental math correctly :)

[image]

Comment: can you add an expected output ?

Comment: @Clegane done - see above!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using explode before using crosstab ?

```
#import ast
#df['ColName2007.1099']=df['ColName2007.1099'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df = df.explode('ColName2007.1099')
df = pd.crosstab(df['ColName2007.1099'],columns=df['Category'],margins=True)
print(df)
'''
Category          Class A  Class B  Class D  All
ColName2007.1099                                
org1                    2        3        1    6
org2                    3        2        2    7
org3                    2        1        0    3
org4                    1        0        1    2
All                     8        6        4   18
'''
```

Note, the data you gave as an example does not match your expected output (For example, there is no **Class C** in the data you provided.
). But it works correctly in the data you provided. If this is not what you want, please provide data that can be copied and pasted and compatible with the expected output.